# Evaluate SPListItem field values using debugger

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, debugging

How do I evaluate SPListItem field values using VS debugger? Best I get is only a list of Field names, but not values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

oListItem["Assigned To"]

where oListItem is the name of your Item and "Assigned To" is the name of the field.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Never knew you can use it like that. I was trying to use Locals windows, but i see i mmust use Immediate Window. Thanks.